# Set min-width of content with viewport meta tag

Tags: html, responsive-design, meta-tags

I need to set the min width of content to 480px so that anyone viewing on a screen <= to that will have to scroll accross to view the content. The reason being for this is that it is impossible to make the layout work below this resolution.

Here's what I have

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,  initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
```

I need something like this but obviously this doesn't work

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,, min-width=480px,  initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1">
```

Comment: Are you trying to set the min-width of content that is on the page you mean? Why not use a media query?

Comment: It's as simple as setting a `min-width` on your `<body>` element.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040408/achieving-min-width-with-viewport-meta-tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to set the min width of the content on the page, not the viewport itself.[This article](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html) might help you out.

You are probably looking to do:

```
@media all and (max-width: 480px) {
    // styles assigned when width is smaller than 480px;

}
```

Something like this, in that block you can sent the styles for content on screens that have a width of 480px and lower.

Hope that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution to have the responsive version of a web only for tablet and desktop.

This this code we disable the mobile version dynamically. On mobile:

```
<!-- Meta Responsive -->
<meta id="myViewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<script>
window.onload = function () {
    if(screen.width <= 767) {
        var mvp = document.getElementById('myViewport');
        mvp.setAttribute('content','width=767');
    }
}
</script>
<!-- End of Meta Responsive -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of codes and achieved some good results doing a sort of realoading the viewport... But, I think that the best way is to create a full-responsive web site (up to 320px ;)

Thats the best aproach:

```js
<script>
//VIEWPORT

function mobileFriendly() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
            var ww = ( document.documentElement.clientWidth < window.screen.width ) ? jQuery(window).width() : window.screen.width; //get proper width
            var mw = 725; 
            //alert ("width" + ww);
            var ratio = ww / mw; //calculate ratio
            //alert ("ratio: " + ratio);
                if( ratio < 1 ){ //smaller than minimum size
                    jQuery("meta[name='viewport']").attr('content', 'initial-scale=' + ratio + ', maximum-scale=' + ratio + ', minimum-scale=' + ratio + ', user-scalable=yes, width=' + mw);
                }else{ //regular size
                    jQuery("meta[name='viewport']").attr('content', 'initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes, width=' + ww);
                }
            }
        }, 600);
    }
    jQuery( document ).ready( function(){
    mobileFriendly()
    });
    window.addEventListener("orientationchange", mobileFriendly, false);

</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta content="user-scalable=yes, maximum-scale=1.6, width=device-width, initial-scale=1, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" name="viewport">
```

Answer (score -2):

Your second solution does in fact work -- what you might not have seen is that you have 2 commas after `width=device-width`, which is probably why you don't have it working. I've copied it and had no problems.

Sometimes fresh eyes does it all.

Edit : 
However, yes, in your case, a media query is exactly what you need.

Answer (score -4):

```
<script>
        //viewport just for screens under/with 480px width other screen widths show the whole page resized
        if(screen.width <= 480) {
            document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;");} 
        //for devices with more and less/equal than 480px width 
        window.onresize = changeViewport;
            function changeViewport(){
                if(screen.width <= 480) {
                    document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;");} 
                if(screen.width > 480) {
                    document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", "");}           
                }
    </script>
```

Comment: JavaScript is overkill in this case.

Comment: This kind of JavaScript manipulation of meta works fine based on my experience.