# GWT app running on mobile

Tags: android, css, gwt

I will be running my GWT generated Java script file on android and I am trying to get my UI to look the same regardless of the size of the mobile screen.  Most of my views have 5 to 6 widgets ,  buttons, Textboxes mostly.  I have put them in a FlexTable for now but maybe there is a better way to lay out the widgets?
My main question however is about how to use CSS to layout my widgets so the look and feel is the same across all screen sizes.  Is this possible to do using CSS? If so would anyone have any CSS examples that focus on widget positioning?

Comment: Not sure if it applies to gwt but you need a responsive ui to accomplish that like the bootstrap framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For GWT on various screen sizes (and to handle landscape, portrait rotation) I use media queries.  In this way you can define css rules for each screen size.

For example in the following below I never need myContentPanel to be larger than 450, but that is too large for iPhone/Android portrait views:

```
@media all and (max-width: 10024px) {
    /*styles for narrow desktop browsers and iPad landscape */
       .myContentPanel{
         width: 450;
    }    
}


@media all and (max-width: 320px) {
   /*styles for iPhone/Android portrait*/
      .myContentPanel {
         width: 320;
    }

}
```

Here is a more complete css example http://snipplr.com/view/67341/

There is a great tutorial using jQuery here http://css-tricks.com/resolution-specific-stylesheets/

You can see more here at:
http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Answer (score 0):

You can use    [ViewPort Meta tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#language)   to maintain proper `widths and heights` for your web applications on `mobile` devices too.. with out changing all the `layouts` .

```
The viewport meta tag to control layout on mobile browsers.
```

See the below question also ,which I already answered to set the viewport .

[Achieving min-width with viewport meta tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15040408/achieving-min-width-with-viewport-meta-tag/15045700#15045700)

And also  have  a  look at @media  tag as user1258245 said